# Как добавить виджет vk на сайт на React?

Tags: reactjs, vkontakte-api

При добавлении виджета vk на сайт React возникла проблема: при добавлении данного кода в реакт компонент

```html
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 0, width: "220", height: "400"}, 1);
</script>
```

возникает ошибка Cannot find name 'mode'